# CORDOVA - I'm trying to open the mail app but instead of opening the dashboard it opens a new mail

Tags: reactjs, cordova, email

Hi i am using cordova for my mobile application I'm trying to open the mail app (gmail.outlook, whatever) but the only available plugin I could find is cordova-plugin-email which allows me to open the mail but instead of opening the dashboard it opens a new mail to send Is there a way to just open the inbox ?

```
const handleOpenMailApp = () => {
    window.cordova.plugins.email.open();
};
```